# Preposition on, in & against, on

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which of these statements is correct?

On/In
a. Lying in the bed
or
b. Lying on the bed

Against/On
a. Leaning against the wall
or
b. Leaning on the wall

Answer (score 1):

They are not statements, just phrases, and they could all be correct.

Someone is *lying in [the] bed* when they are under the covers as though ready for sleep. They are *lying on the bed* when they are lying down on top of the covers, or with the covers removed.

Something like a broom handle (or a person!), or something flat like a folding chair that has been folded, would be described as *leaning against the wall* of a room. Using *on* here wouldn't be wrong, but *leaning on the wall* suggests to me a person standing out of doors and resting their elbows on the top of a low wall.

Comment: Right, in a nutshell. Let's see if you get the upvotes  you deserve. I'm keeping track of correct answers that are not properly upvoted.